# Define a loop as a function to reuse

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I have the following loop that I use several times:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < $options.length; i++) { //...
```

Rather than repeat myself with that code everytime I want to use that loop, I'd like to turn that into a function.

I've tried the following but get an error "i is undefined"

```
function optionLoop( $options, callback) {
    for(var i = 0; i < $options.length; i++) {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    optionLoop($options, function(){
         // Do it
    });
```

But that isn't working. How can I turn a loop into a reusable function to which I can pass another function? And one more question... am I crazy for wanting to do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should pass the loop values into your callback:

```
function optionLoop( $options, callback) {
    for(var i = 0; i < $options.length; i++) {
        callback(i, $options[i]);
    }
}
```

Then, when you call it, use them in your callback function:

```
optionLoop($options, function(index, value) {
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vGHK5/

---

**Update:** if you want to be able to break out of the loop from within the function, use this:

```
function optionLoop( $options, callback) {
    for(var i = 0; i < $options.length; i++) {
        if ( callback(i, $options[i]) === false ) break;
    }
}
```

Then just return `false` if you want to break.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vGHK5/1/

Comment: Awesome, Joseph, thank you! What is the "value" parameter you passed to function in the second snippet?

Comment: @j-man86 - Check out the fiddle. It's the value of the array at position `index`.

Comment: Is that something that JS interprets automatically? i.e. built in variable for arrays?

Comment: If I wanted to use "break" inside of that function... should that just change to return false; ??

Comment: @j-man86 - You'd need to change the `optionLoop()` function to test the return value: `if (false === callback(i, $options[i])) { break; }`. Then you could return `false` from within your callback to stop the loop.

Answer (score 3):

are you trying to access `i` in the callback? you might want to pass that to `callback`